# Links broken on the authors page

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, blog

In addition to a few small inconsistencies- it seems the Author's page on the SO blog doesn't support markdown so there's a few links that look a bit odd, and unlinky. Assuming anyone ever reads it, this looks bad. Specifically this occurs with Arie and balpha's profiles there.

[image: Author profiles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! Seems that when we migrated from using Git to Wordpress, this broke. I'll add this to our bug list to fix.